# L.C.M of two numbers in C

Tags: c, dev-c++, lcm

So, here is my code to calculate [L.C.M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) (Least common multiple) without using [G.C.D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor):

```
int lcm(int x, int y){

    int max = 0, min = 0, ans = 0;

    if(y >= x){
        max = y;
        min = x;    
        if(y % x == 0) return y;
    }else {
        max = x;
        max = y;
        if(x % y == 0) return x;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= max ; i++){
        if( (max*i) % min == 0){
            ans = max * i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ans;
}
```

and here is the `main`:

```
int main(){

    int u, v;

    printf("Input two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &u, &v);
    puts("");
    printf("LCM(%d, %d): %d",u , v, lcm(u, v));

    return 0;  
}
```

It works perfectly for inputs like `4 8`,`7 21` and everything else **in which the first number is smaller**. An example:

[It takes a lot of time to run if the value of first input is higher and does nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvMyf.png)

**What am I doing wrong here?**

I am using Dev-C++.

Comment: In your else condition you've: max = x; max = y; It should be max = x; min = y;

Comment: @TotallyNoob OMG!! Such a fool I am!! *facepalm* Thanks anyways!

Comment: Should I delete this?

Comment: Note `max*i` can readily overflow when `max > 65535`

Comment: In C I know the operator `>=`, which I think is what you mean in this line `if(y => x){`. Does your code really compile like shown?

Comment: oops sorry! that's actually ```>=``` in my code! thanks for pointing out! I'll edit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `else` statement inside the `lcm` function, it should be `min = y`. 
That was the mistake I was making. Thanks [TotallyNoob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9345287/totallynoob) for pointing it out.

Comment: OK, it would be nice if you think about it. Good luck and have a lot of fun!

Comment: @thebusybee Mark as what? Do you mean "accept"? Why do you want this answer (written by question-OP) to be accepted? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Because this question will be shown as answered and marked. When you are researching on a problem here on SO, which questions do you click first? With 0 answers, with at least 1 answer, or with a marked answer? Well, that's why. ;-)